# Distributing iOS app through Worklight 6.1 Appcenter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

Is it required to have Apple Enterprise subscription to distribute iOS app through appcenter, or is there any method to iOS device (iOS 7.1) accecpt app from it with standard subscription? I tried everything but get error (cannot connect to ...) when i press download.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

All applications managed through the Application Center must be packaged for "[Ad Hoc Distribution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html)".

With an iOS developer account, you can share your application with up to 100 iOS devices.

With an iOS enterprise account, you can share your in-house application with an unlimited number of iOS devices.

See [iOS Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/distribute.html) and [iOS Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) for details.

Comment: I tried with "ad hoc" distribution, but got "cannot connect to..." as I mentioned. Everything else is correct (official ssl key,...).

Comment: Then the question is do you have access from the mobile device to the IPA?

Comment: Yes I has. The download button point to correct "itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url= ...." url, and it has correct XML That point to correct ipa, and its downloadable.

Comment: Did you try to install the same app with iTunes? Is it installing to your device?